# UILabel to display Emoji emotions rather than their unicode values \ueXXXX

Tags: objective-c

I'm retrieving values from a server in XML format, the server sends the following string:
"This is a nice string with Emoji \ue056\ue056\ue056\ue057\ue057\ue056\ue056"

I have been struggling to make my UILabel display the emoji icons rather the following

\ue056\ue056\ue056\ue057\ue057\ue056\ue056

I have tried

```
[chatText setText:[chatString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\u" withString:@"\\u"]];
```

Not much luck. Being desperate I have done the following:

```
[chatText setText:[[chatString cStringUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\u" withString:@"\\u"]];
```

Note: Assigning the following string does the trick:

```
[chatText setText:@"\ue056\ue056\ue056\ue057\ue057\ue056\ue056"];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would need to go through each of the characters, and use `stringWithFormat:@"%C"` for each of the emoji characters:

```
// Loop through string by characters, and then do something like:
// NSString *emoji = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 16-bit Unicode character (unichar) here];
NSString *emoji = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0xe415];
chatText.text = [chatText.text stringByAppendingString:emoji];
```

Check out the [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)

Comment: Thank you very much chown for your help. Im afraid it does not quite give me anything other than some Chinese characters. I have tried it on my physical iPhone and not the simulator to eliminate any possibility that the simulator might not have the emoji in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a stringHandler class that contains the following function to overcome this issue, which pretty much solved my problem:

```
+ (NSString *) mapEmojiFromServer:(NSString *) inString
{
    inString = [inString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
    inString = [inString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[@"ue001" lowercaseString] withString:@"\ue001"];
.
.
.

    return inString;
}
```

I haven't noticed a performance issue other than the IDE getting crazy when navigating and scrolling through the page that contains this 2000 lines  function

Thanks a lot for your help.